# Buses from Jaisalmer to Khuri

Tags: india, buses

I read that buses to Khuri go from a private bus stand in Jaisalmer. I would like to know at what times do these buses depart and arrive to Khuri.

Additionally, please tell me when I can catch a bus on my way back.

Comment: Where's Khuri? Not heard of the place.

Comment: A small village southwest of Jaisalmer. I just returned from there a few hours ago. I got all the info that one can possibly get so I'll answer it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the buses to Khuri go from any of the two private bus stands in Jaisalmer.

Times of departure are as follows:

From Jaisalmer to Khuri:

- 9:30
- 13:00
- 14:00
- 15:00
- 17:00

Back from Khuri to Jaisalmer:

- 8:00
- 9:30
- 10:00
- 11:00
- 14:30

If you want to learn more about how to get to Khuri or how to find a bus station in the first place go to my blog post [here](http://india.thefalljourney.com/2012/03/12/jaisalmer-part-1/).